# TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' even if I check that it is not

Tags: typescript

I get this error from TS compiler: "TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'" in the following code:

```
const routeParamsCheck = (
  routeParams: unknown
): routeParams is { slug: string; locale: string } => {
  return (
    routeParams !== null &&
    typeof routeParams === 'object' &&
    'slug' in routeParams &&
    'locale' in routeParams
  );
};
```

I would like to know why it happens at this line: 'slug' in routeParams (it is quite obvious for me that routeParams can not be null at this point). What is the right way to rewrite this code. Thanks!

Comment: FYI This is a known [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28131) of typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, after the line `routeParams !== null`, typescript still considers the type to be `unknown`. Ie, nothing has changed as far as the types are concerned. I'm not sure why this is (perhaps it's a bug or known limitation of the `unknown` type), but there's a pretty simple fix you can do: just swap the order of the first two lines:

```
  return (
    typeof routeParams === 'object' &&
    routeParams !== null &&
    'slug' in routeParams &&
    'locale' in routeParams
  );
```

That way the first line will narrow `unknown` to `object | null`, and `object | null` can be narrowed to `object` by the second line.